# How can I call back a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to the jquery codeverse. I would like to know how to call back function CSZ after a document resize. Here is my current setup:

```
$(document).ready(function CSZ () {|CODE|});
```

Then later, I want to call the code back with this function:

```
$(window).resize(CSZ);
```

It seems to be a very simple concept that just isn't working for me.

Comment: You have scope issues.

Answer (score 4):

Declare the function on its own. You can then reference it for both callbacks:

```
function CSZ() {
    // Do stuff
}
$(document).ready(CSZ);
$(window).resize(CSZ);
```

Currently, `CSZ` is a [*named function expression*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). The identifier `CSZ` will only be in scope *inside* the function it identifies. By changing to to follow my example, you make `CSZ` a function *declaration* instead. It will then be available anywhere within the scope in which it appears (and descendant scopes thereof).

Answer (score 1):

In your current code the symbol `CSZ` will only be accessible from inside the function body itself; it's actually a [language feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression).

In order for this to work as expected, your function needs to be declared like this, on its own and in the global scope:

```
function CSZ () {|CODE|}
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
$(document).ready(CSZ);

$(window).resize(CSZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CSZ () {|CODE|}

$(document).ready(CSZ)

$(window).resize(CSZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the function you declared isn't declared as a window variable.

You could do this :

```
$(document).ready(window.CSZ=function(){...});
$(window).resize(CSZ);
```

Or you could follow this more common pattern :

```
$(function(){
    function CSZ(){
       ...
    };
    CSZ();
    $(window).resize(CSZ);
});
```